# The muometric positioning system, how does it work exactly?

Tags: leptons, gps

While GPS uses light signals to determine the location of a device, I just learned that something similar can be done using cosmic muons rather than light, see e.g. [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1038/s41598-020-75843-7).

The idea, as I understand is, is completely analogous as the idea underlying GPS. There is a
muon detector that we want to locate (let's call this the *device*), and there are some some reference muon detectors, some distance above the device, that play a role analogous to GPS satellites. Suppose one of the reference detectors registers a muon at some initial time $t$, and the device registers that same muon at a later time $t'$. Then, ignoring relativity effects etc., it follows that the distance between the device and the reference detector must be given by $d = c(t'-t)$, as the muons can be assumed to travel almost exactly at the speed of light $c$. With multiple, spatially separated, reference detectors, the so obtained information about the distances between the device and each of these detectors can be used to pinpoint the exact location of the device.

This all seems very clear to me, except for two things:

**Q1:** How does one know for certain that the muon that registers in the device at time $t'$ is actually the same muon that registered at time $t$ in the reference detector?

**Q2:** The device measures $t'$. But in order to determine its own position (via $d$) it also needs to know the value $t$. How does the device know about the latter? It seems an additional communication channel is necessary.